# Adding Permissions in Manifest.JSON for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to add `nativeMessaging` permission in my already published extension on Chrome Store. I see sometimes Chrome disables extensions and notifies users to approve the added permissions.

I want to ask; do `Chrome Store` and `Chrome` browser disable all extensions that change `permissions` property in `manifest.json` no matter what? Or are only specific permissions are handled in this way?

Comment: All permissions that have a warning trigger disabling.

Comment: What ones have trigger disabling please?

Comment: its in the documentation, but its outdated. best bet is to publish another extension and try there. look at optional permissions too.